# how to use ansible with_subelements

Tags: ansible

Here is my database yaml file:

```
apn_operation:
    action: create
    epg_version: 4G
    apn_name: internet_jack
    access-restrictions selection-mode: public
    routing-instance: sgi_nat
    pgw-enabled: yes
    uplink-dscp-map: test
    allow-rule-space:
      - RS_Mobile
      - RS_Mobile_OCC
    name-server:
      - ip_address: 10.0.0.1
        priority: 10
      - ip_address: 10.0.0.2
        priority: 20
```

Here is my playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - apn_operation.yaml

  tasks:
  - name: show content
    debug:
       msg: "{{item}}"
    with_subelements:
    - "{{apn_operation}}"
    - name-server
```

when I ran the playbook. I got the following error:

> TASK [show content] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>   fatal: [11RRvEPG01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got 'OPTUS-QCIDSCP'"}

I don't know what the problem is. can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apn_operation` is dictionary. It's not possible to iterate a dictionary. It's possible to use [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) but this is not what you're looking for.

`with_subelements` is able to iterate a list where each item is a dictionary that comprises another list. For example

```
apn_operation:
  - action: create
    name-server:
      - ip_address: 10.0.0.1
        priority: 10
      - ip_address: 10.0.0.2
        priority: 20
```

works as expected and gives

```
    "msg": [
        {
            "action": "create"
        }, 
        {
            "ip_address": "10.0.0.1", 
            "priority": 10
        }
    ]

    "msg": [
        {
            "action": "create"
        }, 
        {
            "ip_address": "10.0.0.2", 
            "priority": 20
        }
    ]
```

Comment: @jackliu Please accept and upvote his answer if it answered your question.